# Invoking a command with variable evaluation in Octopus Deploy Powershell script

Tags: powershell, variables, octopus-deploy

I have a simple Powershell script that I execute during an Octopus Deploy installation. This line works fine:

```
& $exe install --autostart
```

I runs an application identified by $exe variable with command line arguments "install --autostart".

Now I need to expand command line arguments with a value evaluated from a variable:

```
& $exe install --autostart -servicename=$serviceName
```

"$serviceName" is the variable that gets its value during the script execution. Whatever I do it's passed to the line above by variable name, not the value, e.g. it's passed as "$serviceName". I tried single and double quotes, nothing helps. As long it's a command invocation (triggered by the "&" symbol in the beginnging of the line), the rest of the line is interpreted verbatim, no variable substitions.

I used last couple of hours trying to figure this out and this is driving me mad. Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some testing on my side and it looks like if you'd like the variable passed in to the command to be evaluated as a variable it needs whitespace on both sides.  So you would want to define your variable as `$serviceName = "-servicename=*name*"` or if that is not possible then create a new variable just before running the command

```
$tmpServicename = "-servicename=$($serviceName)"
& $exe install --autostart $tmpServiceName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!